# Exclude specific holidays from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have this query that I'm using to pull records from my DB:

```
SELECT dateAdded, claimedDate, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateAdded, claimedDate) AS output FROM leads 
WHERE HOUR(dateAdded) >= '9' 
AND HOUR(dateAdded) < '18' 
AND DAYOFWEEK(dateAdded) != 7 
AND DAYOFWEEK(dateAdded) != 1
```

As it stands, I'm currently only selecting records with a timestamp that falls between 9:00am - 5:00pm, Monday through Friday. I also need to be able to exclude the following major holidays: New Year's Day, Memorial Day, Independence Day, Labor Day, Thanksgiving, and Christmas.

I need those holidays excluded for all time. For example, the query should exclude all records that occur on the fourth Thursday of Nov (Thanksgiving), regardless of the year.

This doesn't necessarily need a MySQL-only solution. If it's easier to do a hybrid PHP/MySQL solution that would also work great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Off the top of my head you can always hardcode the dates in (terrible terrible I know, but if you do like 50 years I think you are safe), or write the rules yourself in a php class. Calendar app creators need to be able to determine when the holidays are so you definitely can programatically.

Comment: a lot of those holidays are 'floating'. they're not a fixed day (e.g. christmas = dec 24). easter/thanksgiving/labor day are all based on other parameters "first X after Y on Z with ..." type things. There is **NO** simple way to accounting for that in a single query unless you want to load up a few zillion lines of pointless logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a table of dates that meet your "holiday" criteria, and then you `JOIN` to that table.

### [Here's an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef5f4/2)

Otherwise, you'll need to simply exclude them...

```
... WHERE dateAdded NOT IN ('2012-07-04', ...)
```

**Update**

[This solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29221/1) uses a `JOIN` to omit holidays.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing this join against the dates table? Also, as far as populating the table goes, do I just hard-code the dates for the next 10 years? That doesn't seem very future proof.

Comment: @Jeremy I updated my answer with an example using a dates table. If you don't use this approach, hard-coding is really your only other option. Do you really wish to write a function to check the date each holiday falls on every year?

Comment: This looks like a good solution, only my dateAdded column uses the datetime format, so the join isn't working as intended due to the inclusion of hours, minutes, and seconds. [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5476/1).

Comment: You can also do a [sub-query using exist](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) if you prefer not to do a `JOIN`.

Comment: My MySQL skills are pretty basic. Do you mind showing me how that would work in this specific instance?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function, is_holiday, and then add to your select statement. As so.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `is_holiday`(nDate Date) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
declare isholiday boolean;
set isholiday = false;

if month(nDate)=1 and day(nDate)=1 then set isholiday = true;
elseif month(nDate)=7 and day(nDate)=4 then set isholiday = true;
elseif month(nDate)=12 and day(nDate)=25 then set isholiday = true;
elseif month(nDate)=9 and day(nDate) between 1 and 7 and weekday(nDate) = 0 then set isholiday = true;
elseif month(nDate)=11 and day(nDate) between 22 and 28 and weekday(nDate) = 3 then set isholiday = true;
end if;

RETURN isholiday;
end
```

add to your code...

```
and not is_holiday(dateAdded)
```